# Laravel middleware and unique data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I have middleware which logout banned user and redirect them to the specific page where they read about the reason they're banned, but the issue is the URL can be set for any user id and returning as much as users load it.

**Example** `site.co/banned/55` then you just change `55` to other users id and it loads over and over.

## What I want

I want to load this returning page with **one time token** and if they try to reload this page or share the link etc. they won't be able to. Unless they try to login and with new token see this page.

## Code

`middleware`

```
class NotBlocked
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            $user = Auth::user();

            if(count($user->bans) > 0){

                foreach($user->bans as $ban){
                    $expires = $ban->blocked_on;
                }

                if ($expires >= Carbon::now())
                {
                    Auth::logout();
                    return redirect()->route('banned', $user->id)->with('warning', 'Your session has expired because your account is deactivated.');
                }
            }

        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

`route`

```
Route::get('banned/{id}', 'Front\HomeController@banned')->name('banned');
```

`route groups`

```
Route::middleware('notBlocked')->group(function () {
//all routes here
});
```

`kernel`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        // middlewares
        'notBlocked' => \App\Http\Middleware\NotBlocked::class,
];
```

**PS**

I want to replace `{id}` part in my route and `return redirect()->route('banned', $user->id)` user id in middleware with token which works only once.

Any idea?

Comment: You could create a [signed route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls#signed-urls), this way you can only access the page if you have the correct links which is unguessable. This does prevent others from viewing the page but not prevent the 'correct' user from revisiting it by looking at the url in its browser history.

Comment: Furthermore your `foreach($user->bans as $ban)` loop gets the last expiry time, I suppose you want the longest lasting ban time? You will need to alter the loop body for that.

Comment: @milo526 your route suggestion is something that i think might works for second comment i have no idea what you said :D, the reason I looped bans is because i let each user to be ban 3 times before i remove their accounts. so I needed to check all those 3 ban to see if any of them is valid due to current time. please share an answer with \me so it can be more clear to me. Thanks

Comment: I think what @milo526 is getting at with the loop is that you check the expires time after the loop finishes executing where the value will be the last record that was inserted. If you want the longest expires just check if the current is `greaterThanOrEqualTo` the current and assign the value if it is true. If you are working with carbon dates: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/f99183761cab1562392fcbbd93d868ad7c0d3fb4/src/Carbon/Traits/Comparison.php#L145

Comment: @adam I am using carbon yes, so you means i do this instead of mine? `if($expires greaterThanOrEqualTo Carbon::now())` ?

Comment: @mafortis found answer ? did u try pass another param `route/{id}/{strtotime}`

Comment: @Hamelraj no man, got confused with comments. I've tried signed route didn't understand it :(

Comment: no one can provide an answer?! i need this to work :/